# MATLAB- how to read certain columns from a text file using an iterative manner

Tags: matlab

I would like to read a csv file having an irregular matrix. 
What I need to read is A column (Dates) and B column (Measurements) in an iterative manner. 
Below is an example format.

```
       A, B, C,        A, B, C,        A, B, C   ...  ...                               
4/1/1970, 2, 5, 3/1/1971, 6, 5, 2/1/1972, 7, 5   ...  ...
7/1/1970, 3, 5, 7/1/1971, 2, 5, 4/1/1972, 3, 5   ...  ... 
        ,  ,  , 4/1/1971, 8, 5, 5/1/1972, 6, 5   ...  ... continued with this format
        ,  ,  ,         ,  ,  , 7/1/1972, 8, 5
        ,  ,  ,         ,  ,  , 8/1/1972, 11,5
```

Ultimately, I want to get

```
        A, B
 4/1/1970, 2
 7/1/1970, 3
 3/1/1971, 6       
 7/1/1971, 2
     .
     .
```

Can any experts help me? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried ?  SO is here to help.  If you need your work done for you consult a professional software developer in your home city.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSVIMPORT. It reads the csv file into a cell array or matrix.

See:
    http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23573-csvimport

If you read it into a matrix M you can then easily loop through the data with two for-loops. Warning, I'm writing pseudo code here, so it's not tested. Good luck.

```
for row = 1:size(M,1)
    for col = 1:size(M,2)
        if M(row,col) != ""
            % do some work
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) for that purpoose

```
fid = fopen('data.txt');
A = textscan(fid, '%s%f%f%s%f%f%s%f%f', 'Delimiter', ',', 'Headerlines', 1);
fclose(fid);
```

`A` is a cell. The dates are read as strings (`%s`), while the numbers are read as doubles (`%f`). Where the numbers or dates are missing you get a `NaN` or `''` in `A`, respectively.